# What will happen if phone is turned off while CodePush is installing the update?

Tags: android, react-native, code-push

Assume we use sync() method to install the update. If the phone is turned off while the update is being installed, will the app be able to re-start normally? Also, will the plugin automatically tries to install the update again?

Environment:
React-Native 0.24 (Android)

Answer (score 3):

Under the covers, the `sync` method performs three individual steps in order to keep the running app up-to-date:

1. Checking to see whether there is an available update on the server. If the phone was turned off in the middle of this check, then the app would be completely fine, and when the phone was restarted, this check would simply happen again (when `sync` is called) and have the same response as it would have previously.
2. Downloading an available update. If the phone was turned off in the middle of this process, then the app would be completely fine. When the phone was restarted, the call to `sync` would discover the incomplete update, delete it and re-download it. We don't currently support resuming a previously started update download, but we do ensure that no update will actually be run unless it is complete and passes an integrity check (e.g. did we get the right content that we expected).
3. Installing an update that has been downloaded. Once an update is downloaded, it is effectively "orphaned" on disk, and isn't actually made available until the CodePush runtime "installs" it, which means that it updates an internal metadata file which indicates the update that should be run on subsequent app starts. Depending on the specified install mode, this step might also need to programmatically restart the app. If the phone was shut off in the middle of this process, then the app would be fine. The downloaded update would continue to be "orphaned", and the next time the app starts, it would run the previous version, and the subsequent call to `sync` would discover the update and re-download it again. Since it would be such an edge case for the install step to be disturbed, we don't currently support detecting a previously downloaded and complete update on disk, that we could simply install. We would re-download it again, which thanks to the server's support for differential updates, hopefully would just be a few files. Over time, I'd like to see us optimize this use case, but we have yet to see it represent an issue.

Let me know if you have any other questions, or if I didn't completely answer your question. We've done a lot of work to ensure that the React Native plugin is resilient to these kind of unexpected disruptions, and I'd love to hear more feedback around it!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply!